# Filtering Forms in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I am making a small project to rate salesmen. I have regions and each region has its salesmen. So, if region "blahblah" is selected, form should show salesmen choices which are related to that region. I have found some answers via stackoverflow, but it still shows all salesmen, regardless of their regions.

My model is this:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Salesman(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region,
                               related_name='region',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

class Rating(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1,6)]
    salesman = models.ForeignKey(Salesman,
                                 related_name='salesman',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False)
    sent_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone
```

I found modified `__init__` method for my forms.py:

```
class RateAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rating

    def __init__(self, region_id=None, **kwargs):
        super(RateAddForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if region_id:
            self.fields['salesman'].queryset = Salesman.objects.filter(region=region_id)
```

And also my views.py is this:

```
def report_add(request, region_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(region_id)
        form = RateAddForm(request.POST, region_id=region_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = "Thanks!"
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse(message)
        else:
            print("Something went wrong!")
            form = RateAddForm()
    else:
        form = RateAddForm(request.POST)
    return render(request,
                  'account/report.html',
                  {'form': form})
```

It still shows me all salesmen on my database, even if i choose a region. How to solve this problem that form should show only salesmen of selected region. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know, but this looks as if the queryset gets expanded into a choices instance by the superclass `__init__ `method?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `self.base_fields['salesman'].queryset` instead of
`self.fields['salesman'].queryset` (i.e "base_fields" instead of "fields").

(That's what I do when I need to filter in Admin forms)